# ggplot on github compatibility with R/ R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shiny

Is there a compatibility issue with the latest version of R (3.4.2) and ggplot2? My R Shiny app was working two days ago. The plots stopped working yesterday and I noticed that ggplot2 was moved to `tidyverse/ggplot2' in github. I updated the package, 
LoadGithubPackage('ggplot2', 'tidyverse/ggplot2')
but still the plots do not look right anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Mine's still working fine, however when using ggplot I'm doing something like this in the server function for shiny:

```
  output$GOOG.forecast <- renderPlot({
    b <- GOOG.forecast
    plot(b)
  })
```

Just remember when you're doing plot outputs in shiny you have to define the data within the output function (I know it's kinda weird) but this has always worked for me. Otherwise consider using dygraphs if it's appropriate.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would try reverting to CRAN's version of ggplot2 with

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

and see if that fixes it